# get element position from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've got a value from input and an array with length based on value from input... so As example i pressed 3 in input and i'll have var input = 3 and var sir = [0,1,2]... Where i'm wrong when i tried to find sir.indefOf(input) ??

Code:

```
function findPositionInArray(objectToFind, array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (objectToFind == array[i]){
            return array[i].indexOf(objectToFind);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

`console.log(findPositionInArray(input, sir));` returns all the time `0` even if in array the input value exists, i tested it in an array with 50 elements starting from 0 to 49 looking for 5!

Comment: return array.indexOf(objectToFind);

Comment: Why do you return `array[i].indexOf(objectToFind)` if the object is found?

Comment: You've tagged jQuery but there's no sign of jQuery in your code and you turned [Rory's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27150340/1612146) away. Is jQuery available to you or not?

Comment: jQuery can be transformed in native js so yes, its available... I'm interested in algorithm's so doesnt matter if js or jquery. But u didnt make difference between alghoritm's and methods! what Rory suggested was a method!

Comment: He gave me a link for that method so i Voted up! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong : it will stop after the first element because you are returning 0.

It should be :

```
function findPositionInArray(objectToFind, array) {
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(objectToFind == array[i]) found = i;
    }
    return found;
}
```

But you should use, as said, jQuery.inArray() or JS indexOf...

Comment: Typically -1 is returned if the object can't be found in an array instead of false.

Comment: I always use false, I think it's more logical. Could you explain why -1 is better ?

Comment: For one, `$.inArray()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` use that return value; and since arrays can never have negative indices, it fits the bill just fine.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery provides the `$.inArray` helper for this exact purpose:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log($.inArray(1, arr)); // = 0 (the index of '1' in the array)
```

Comment: Why? Here's the jQuery source for the above if you prefer: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.inArray

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, the pure JavaScript solution is `arr.indexOf(element)` which will return either an index to the array, or -1 if the  element does not exist.

Comment: Good answer, however you should be aware that this isn't supported in <IE9.

Comment: I assume OP doesn't support IE unless explicitly noted ^_^ (I use this in my own code, soo....)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There are polyfills for that :)